# how to find if string not exist in array nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, string

I have a string array and i want to check if str2 not exist in str1 flag = true

```
symbols=["A","B","C"];
symbol="D"
if (symbols.indexOf(symbol) === false)
                flag = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when IndexOf doesn't find a symbole it returns -1.
So your code should be

```
if (symbols.indexOf(symbol) === -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (!symbols.includes(symbol)) {
  // symbol is not in symbols
}
```

You can also use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if appropriate.